# Track relative movement of device without internet connection?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I am totally new to Android development and looking for some directions.
I want my app to determine the relative movement of the device real time.
Initially the user will mark his current position.
After this, the app will trace the movement relative to the initial position and create the traversed path.
And with what precision would the data be available i.e. within 1metre/1 foot radius, etc. So here are my queries:

1. Is it possible to develop such an app without having any internet
   connection and with how much precision can I get the data?
2. If internet connection is available, then which technology should I
   use and with how much precision can I get the data?
3. If there is any other better solution then please feel free to
   suggest

**NOTE:** The device does NOT need to transmit this data anywhere i.e. the data stays on the device and not transmitted to server or any other device.

Comment: where is the position data going, is it staying locally in the app only?

Comment: Yes, the device is tracking its own path. The device does not need to send the data to anyone else.

Comment: then no you dont need internet

Comment: Can you please tell me how this can be done with best possible precision?

Comment: @Downvoter, can you please give the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task you need the GPS sensor of the device, no other sensor will work (well).
GPS don't  need Internet.
(However there exist some crippled android phone modells which needs an initial Inernet connection to enable GPS, but this is an special exception).

The relative movement of GPS is (usually) more acurate as the absoulte position.
You can expect an total psoition accuracy about 2-3m accuracy in regions which have an SBAS-aid for GPS: That is US with its WAAS system or Europe with EGNOS, or japan with MSAS, and proably some more.
I have never heard about any published numbers for relative positional accuracy.

The question remains why you need the relative movement (-5m west, 6m north), and not the absoulte one. (To calculate speed you better use the speed attribute of the location).
Probably you meant a sequence of absolute positions, which form a trajectory of the walked or driven path. 
Be carefull at the relative path, here you need more know how. Basically you need the delta x and dy distance between two points. But that depends more on the exact task you have to solve.

You get the relative path by subtracting the start position.

Comment: What would be the accuracy without the SBAS-aid system? "To calculate speed you better use the speed attribute of the location" - does the GPS sensor also give the speed of the device along with the direction of movement? That would be great!

Comment: I am developing this app so that people without access to internet (and thus GMaps) can track their movement. The public implications are not so much important to me as I want this app for personal reasons.

Comment: Just wanted to know what raw data is available through the GPS sensor? Is it latitude and longitude along with some more information? Thanks for your help!

Comment: why don't you read the android docu for Location? on a smartphone you never access the raw data, you simply have no acces to that. The android and ios APIsprovide: time (might be adjusted, by the OS), lat, lon, course, speed, altitude horicontalAccuracyEstimationMeters (is related to lat,lon), isLocationValid.